# Bring timing to Snake animation along border

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I wanted to make snake like movement along the border.After struggling with animation came across this code from @Gershom Maes, that does something almost similar to what I'm looking for.

Also I think, it would be cooler to make the border rounded instead of sharp.

Is there any way I can make it circle around 2 times and then repeat it only after every 3mins or so? The issue is you don't want users to pay attention to it all the time but once in a while.

```css
.ex1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px; height: 150px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.ex1.snake-border::after { content: none; }
.ex2.snake-border::before { content: none; }

/* snake-border stuff: */
@keyframes snake-border-head {
  
  /*
  The snake's "head" stretches across a side of its container.
  The moment this head hits a corner, it instantly begins to
  stretch across the next side. (This is why some keyframe
  moments are repeated, to create these instantaneous jumps)
  */
  
  90% { left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 40%; }
  90% { left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; }
  100% { left: 0; top: 0; width: 40%; height: 0; } 0% { left: 0; top: 0; width: 40%; height: 0; }
  
  15% { left: 60%; top: 0; width: 40%; height: 0; }
  15% { left: 100%; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; }
  25% { left: 100%; top: 0; width: 0; height: 40%; }
  
  40% { left: 100%; top: 60%; width: 0; height: 40%; }
  40% { left: 100%; top: 100%; width: 0; height: 0; }
  50% { left: 60%; top: 100%; width: 40%; height: 0; }
  
  65% { left: 0; top: 100%; width: 40%; height: 0; }
  65% { left: 0; top: 100%; width: 0; height: 0; }
  75% { left: 0; top: 60%; width: 0; height: 40%; }
  
}
@keyframes snake-border-tail {
  
  /*
  The "tail" of the snake is at full length when the head is at 0
  length, and vice versa. The tail always at a 90 degree angle
  from the head.
  */

  90% { top: 0%; height: 40%; }
  100% { left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; } 0% { left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; }
  
  15% { width: 40%; }
  25% { left: 100%; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; }
  
  40% { height: 40%; }
  50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; width: 0; height: 0; }
  
  65% { left: 0%; width: 40%; }
  75% { left: 0; top: 100%; width: 0; height: 0; }
  
}

.snake-border {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #00a0ff;
}
.snake-border::before, .snake-border::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 3px solid #00a0ff;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.snake-border::before { animation-name: snake-border-head; }
.snake-border::after { animation-name: snake-border-tail; }
```

```html
<div class="ex1 snake-border"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with not showing it in between then you could use JS with a timer to add a `.hidden` class to the `snake-border::before, .snake-border::after` that will make the border transparent.